# Call a function after data is rendered in the template: Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm subscribing to a method which is making and API call. Inside the subscribe body, I'm assigning (assigning the first time and modifying the object the second time) the received data to an object in the following way:

```
this.serviceObj.getData()
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.DataObj = {
      ..... some content .....
    }
    this.anotherFunction();
  },
  error => {
    console.log('error');
  },
  );
```

In the subscribe body, once I receive the data, I'm assigning it to the "DataObj", and after the DataObj has the new data it gets rendered in the UI. I want "anotherFunction()" to execute AFTER the "dataObj" is assigned new data and is rendered in the UI. But it looks like the data is being assigned successfully but "anotherFunction()" is getting executed before the new data is successfully rendered in the UI.

I tried using:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.anotherFunction();
}
```

the "anotherFunction()" gets executed after the view is changed if I put it inside the ngAfterViewChecked(), but this keeps executing even when there is a minor change in the template, but I only want it to run when the "DataObj" is changed.

Any suggestions how I can make this work efficiently? (without making ngAfterViewChecked() being executed soo often).

Comment: have you tried `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: I tried doing that, @JasonSpradlin. But reading at Angular's documentation about ngOnChanges, it says "Lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes." So ngOnChanges is not getting executed when I'm receiving the data.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that comes to mind is a "semaphore" based approach. Set a flag `dataReceived` to false. In the .subscribe, set it to true. Then in the `ngAfterViewChecked()` only run the code if `dataReceived` is true.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.dataRetrieved) {
     this.anotherFunction();
     this.dataRetrieved = false;
  }
}
```

I don't like "flag-based" approaches. But this is the only thing that comes to mind to solve this. Maybe someone else has a better solution?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that right now. But as you said, not the best approach. But thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What about a pipe?

It runs right before rendering and you will be able to call `anotherFunction`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'anotherFunction'})
export class AnotherFunctionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): number {

    anotherFunction();

    return value;
  }

  anotherFunction() {
     // do something  
  }

}
```

Usage would be something like this

```
<div> {{ DataObj | anotherFunction }} </div>
```